# R indexing multi-dimensional structure in C extension

Tags: c, r, indexing

I have a multi-dimensional structure in R in which I'm accessing a list on those ways:

**model$a$b** or **model[[5]][[4]]**

But how to do this in a C extension? Right now I'm trying it like that:

**VECTOR_ELT(VECTOR_ETL(model, (R_xlen_t) 4), (R_xlen_t) 3)**

But it behaves more like **model[5][4]** than **model[[5]][[4]]**

Comment: of course I mean VECTOR_ELT not VECTOR_ETL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by using

coerceVector with generic vector (VECSXP) after first VECTOR_ELT

and

coerceVector with integer vector (INTSXP) after second VECTOR_ELT